How to use tlmgr usermode properly without compatibilty issues?
I am moving from the native MacTeX distribution to the Homebrew-packaged texlive. One major difference is I have to use usermode of tlmgr to keep TeX packages up-to-date. I did a little testing but seem to have encountered some compatibility issue.
With a fresh installation of texlive 2024, I did the following:
tlmgr init-usertree
tlmgr --usermode install scheme-basic

This skips all non-relocatable packages such as pdftex, which leads to package incompatibility. For example, the latest array.sty in the latex-tools package (part of scheme-basic) does not work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{test}
  \label{tab:test}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a & b\\
    c & d
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

This first few lines of the compilation log reveals the error:
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with ``pdflatex  -file-line-error   --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/Homebrew) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/Users/ryan/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/ryan/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/Users/ryan/texmf/tex/latex/tools/array.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2024/06/01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2023-11-01' is available.

) (/Users/ryan/texmf/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def) (./test.aux)
./test.tex:10: Undefined control sequence.
\@tabular ->\leavevmode \UseTaggingSocket 
                                          {tbl/hmode/begin}\hbox \bgroup $\c...l.10   \begin{tabular}{cc}

How can I fix this? More importantly, what is the proper way of using tlmgr --usermode? It seems to me that incompatibility is inevitable when some packages are newer than others.

welcome! you don't do this. if you want the latest from ctan, you install mactex. if you want the latest development stuff, you install mactex and probably pull from github, too. if you want to use homebrew, you use homebrew to update and accept the fact that your installation will be a bit outdated. there's no reason to update unless you need to. were you experiencing a problem which you believed an update would fix? you cannot update core latex packages without updating the stuff they depend on any more than you can update safari without updating the stuff it depends on.

Ref.: tlmgr --help or man tlmgr.
Exp.: ran tlmgr with --dry-run in user mode on the OP's installation target1.

I fear this is not be the answer you want to hear ...

Basically, the answer is that you don't do this. There is no 'proper' way to update the installation as a user. If you want the latest from CTAN, you install vanilla from upstream i.e. MacTeX or equivalent. If you want cutting-edge blades you can shred your documents on, you add GitHub. If you want to use a distribution's packages, whether that is homebrew or your favoured Linux distro, you use your system or homebrew package manager to update you TL install and you accept that you system will probably be a bit behind CTAN. Well, even TL is slightly behind CTAN, but homebrew will obviously be behind TL. Except during the annual freeze, TL gets updates from CTAN very fast because there are generally multiple people transforming CTAN packages into TL packages2.
It is possible to use tlmgr in user mode to install collections and packages --- that is, NOT schemes.
Schemes are TeX Live installation schemas. When you install TeX Live, you can choose from various schemes when customising your installation. scheme-basic is a standalone installation of TeX Live. You can't install it in user mode as an add-on to an existing installation.
However, although you can update collections/packages this way, I don't recommend it because there is no guarantee they won't require updates to core LaTeX. There are never any guarantees, but partial updates reduce the probability of ending up with a working system.
Questions you should consider:

Why did you want to switch to homebrew? You don't say, so I have no idea if the answer is a good one or not. But MacTeX or BasicTeX is the most reliable way to install TL on a Mac.
Do you need to update? If TL works, there's no particular need to update it. Just get the homebrew updates as and when.

If the answer to both questions is that you have good reasons, you need to figure out whether those conflicting needs can be met by installing both or modifying the way you install and/or use one of the two. If the Unix-ish install script works on Macs, that might offer you a good option if, say, you want a more custom setup than MacTeX offers.
But you cannot update core LaTeX packages without updating the stuff they depend on any more than you can update Safari without updating the stuff it depends on.
I do think tlmgr could do better here. It spews alarm on the console if I try to do what you did (even in dry-run mode), but I think it should probably either refuse to install schemes or refuse to do so unless --force or some similar option is given. It's hard to think of a scenario in which installing a scheme this way would do anything useful.
1In an unprivileged account which can't touch mine, the system directories or TL and doesn't have sudo rights.
2At least there were. I assume there still are.

Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. To answer some of your questions: 1. the reason that I want to switch is because I am moving my workflow from personal Mac to work Mac, for which I don't have the sudo privilege. The homebrew-packaged version is just the first alternative I am trying out. 2. I don't feel compelled to update every now and then, but an annual update (like most distributions do) feels a little too long. Reading your answer, I guess I can either stick with the homebrew version and update only with brew, or use the Unix install script to install to a writable path.

A major reason that I posted this question here is I am a little confused by the usage of usermode. First, I don't get any warning while doing tlmgr --usermode install scheme-basic. Second, the incompatibility issue I mentioned is not caused by schemes per se. If I do tlmgr --usermode install collection-latex or tlmgr --usermode install latex-tools, the MWE will fail with the same error. That makes me wonder how one could use usermode safely, because any package installed in usermode must be newer than the LaTeX core, leading to potential incompatibility.

In this sense, "usermode" is more like "developer mode", as it requires tremendous caution that a regular user may not exercise.

@Ryan I never install texlive with root privileges and it is not the upstream recommendation. it is the norm on macs, but I can't remember if mactex actually required it and I certainly don't know if it currently does. what I do is make /usr/local/texlive writeable by a special non-privileged user texlive. obviously setting that up requires root, but if you can persuade IT to do that much, you could manage texlive there using a similar account setup.  (texlive doesn't have sudo rights on my machine. /usr/local/texlive is just texlive's home directory.)

you might want to ask about usermode on the texlive mailing list. but you have to understand that tlmgr is not a package manager in the way that apt or homebrew is. it doesn't do a lot of dependency management, for example, so there really isn't anything to stop you breaking things. of course, it is also not system-critical software and it can keep backups, but don't rely on it to warn you if you're breaking tex. It may be useful in development or for installing things your distro doesn't include? or maybe it was just designed when latex didn't change much, since it didn't used to?

Thanks @cfr. Your answer is really helpful.
